# Difference between DISTRIBUTION and PARTITION in db2

Tags: db2

Two performance enhancement features of db2, PARTITION and DISTRIBUTION is confusing me. How can I understand the exact difference between them? And what type of field to be used for PARTITION and what for DISTRIBUTION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the online DB2 Knowledge Centre for your version and operating-system platform, which explains this stuff in depth and gives the syntax. Below is only a summary

For DB2 on Linux/Unix/Windows, A partitioned DB2-instance can run on multiple physical or logical hostnames, but a database in that partitioned instance appears as a single database to applications. There can be logical-partitions (running on the same hostname) or physical-partitions (run on different hostnames) in a shared-nothing arrangement, i.e. different CPUs, different disks, different RAM etc. In a partitioned DB2-instance, tables can be distributed-by-hash ("hash partitioning") on a column chosen by the designer to equally distribute the table data over all chosen partitions. So a column with only 2 discrete values would be unsuitable. The designer can group partitions in as many groupings (partition groups) as make sense for the workload.  To partition your DB2-instance you need a special licence for DB2 , and this configuration is also known as DPF (distributed partitioning feature), and IBM sells (or at please used to sell) a hardware/software solution (IBM Smart Analytics series) with configurations to suit a particular workload. This configuration is common for some warehouse workloads, decision support/OLAP workloads for very large databases.

On large warehouses it is common to combine hash-partitioning and range-partitioning. But they can be separately implemented.

Range-partitioning (partition by range) is a common technique to logically split up a table into multiple separate tables (which can be in different tablespaces/storage objects). In this case it is the table that is partitioned, as distinct from the DB2-instance. The designer chooses a partitioning column  that suits the workload, often the column has geographic scope, or temporal scope (one partition per day/week/month/hour etc) or whatever makes sense logically. The designer usually arranges for the indexes to be also partitioned, although global indexes are allowed. Range-partitioning supports easier roll-in of new partitions on demand, and roll-out of old partitions (as part of table clean up) with minimal concurrency overheads. This is crucial if databases need to remain within a certain size with regular archival of old content that can be sent to tape or long-term less costly storage outside of DB2.